# Implicit derivatives in one line. How do I do it?

Tags: equation-solving, programming, calculus-and-analysis

I have this little script to derive implicitly

```
$PrePrint = # /. {D[y_, x_, NonConstants -> {y_}] :> y'[x]} &;
```

Example:

```
D[x == y^3 + x y, x, NonConstants -> y]
```

> `1 == y + x y'[x] + 3 y^2*y'[x]`

and then, to obtain the expression for `y'[x]`, I use

```
Solve[1 == y + x y'[x] + 3 y^2*y'[x],y'[x]] //FullSimplify
```

How can I get all these steps in one line?

I'd like to have something like

```
$PrePrint = # /. {D[y_, x_, NonConstants -> {y_}] :> y'[x]} &; //Solve...
```

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere…

Comment: Look up `Dt[]`.

Comment: If I saw that, but I want to publish online with the Solve not like having to go to take the result of the derivative and clearance and  y '[x]

Comment: I cannot understand the question at all. You may need a better english translation before posting here.

Comment: Related: [(1945)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1945), [(24422)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24422), [(52284)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52284)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my interpretation of your question is correct, the following code should produce the desired behaviour.

```
prePrint[input_] := 
  Module[{solveFor}, 
   input /. {D[y_, x_, NonConstants -> {y_}] :> (solveFor = y'[x])} //
      If[OwnValues[solveFor] === {}, input, Solve[#, solveFor]] & // 
    FullSimplify];
$PrePrint = prePrint;
```

Test

```
D[x == y^3 + x y, x, NonConstants -> y]
```

> `{{y'[x]] -> (1 - y)/(x + 3 y^2)}}`

Comment: if just that is, thank you, sorry for my English